# Adding customer-defined optional extras to a product in the basket in a django-oscar site

Tags: django-oscar

When adding a product to the basket, our customer is presented with an optional customiser app which works roughly in this way:

- for each product (if the quantity is greater than one) be able to add a personalised name
- for all products, add personalised decals in various positions on the product
- decals are uploaded by the customer, and there's a one-time extra charge if the decal is not in SVG format
- etc...

I have already built the models and calculator which calculates just the above customisation portion of a product. The customiser app is a Vue.js app which sits on the product detail page, and via an API creates a JSON blob that represents the complex customisation, keyed against the user, basket, and product IDs, and the calculator parses this JSON blob to get a price for the customisation, which excludes the product price.

Next up is figuring out how to

- render the customisation cost separate from the product price on the basket line item
- include the customisation cost as part of the product total, and ultimately the basket total

It seems like neither [variants nor attributes](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html) make sense in this case, but a `oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractOption` does. From the pydoc:

> An option that can be selected for a particular item when the product is added to the basket.
>
> For example, a list ID for an SMS message send, or a personalised message to print on a T-shirt.
>
> This is not the same as an 'attribute' as options do not have a fixed value for a particular item. Instead, option need to be specified by a customer when they add the item to their basket.

The "personalised message" on my "T-shirt" can be the customisation JSON blob which is actioned by the warehouse staff before the item is shipped.

However, it doesn't seem like an option affects the price. How can I attach a dynamic price to an option? In a strategy? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Paid product options are not currently supported out of the box in Oscar (see the relevant [ticket](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1515)), but it is possible to implement relatively easily by forking a couple of Oscar apps, and (broadly) doing the following:

1. Create a model for storing the price of an option for a given product (or, if the price is the same for all products for an given option, store it on the `Option` model itself).
2. Override the `Strategy` class methods `fetch_for_line` and `fetch_for_product` to pass the options from the line through to the logic that returns a pricing strategy - override this to look up the price for that option and add it to the base price.

This basic implementation only requires overriding a couple of methods in the `Strategy`, and then storing your prices in a model somewhere. There is room for additional complexity - e.g., if options are mandatory and affect the minimum price, you may want to display that minimum price in search results etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and report back. (And TIL about Mamihlapinatapai, cheers!)